# shell script not executing despite full permissions

Tags: sh

I have a small script that executes fine from my home folder but when moved to a different folder on different partition (EXT4)

```
 $ ls -lah ./build.sh

-rwxrwxr-x 1 olmec(me) olmec(me) 510 Oct 31 20:00 ./build.sh

$ ./build.sh

bash: ./build.sh: Permission denied
```

I have tried chmod 777 build.sh but no difference.
The script is in folder /media/data/source

Data drive partition is mounted in FStab as
UUID=affd0ac6-f3da-4f88-ac22-65d94dc5da8c /media/data ext4 user,user 0 0

Resolved by modifying FStab mount command
UUID=affd0ac6-f3da-4f88-ac22-65d94dc5da8c       media/data      ext4    auto,users,exec                 0       0

Comment: Have you tried `chmod 777 build.sh` before launching it, or launching with `sh build.sh` or `su ./build.sh` ?

Comment: Do you have permission to access it? In which folder you have placed it ? @user115962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably it's on a volume which was mounted with the `noexec` option, I'd check that. If that's not the case, you can still try to find out from `strace bash yourscript`'s output.

Comment: Mount options in FStab - UUID=affd0ac6-f3da-4f88-ac22-65d94dc5da8c /media/data ext4 user,user 0 0

Comment: I modified FStab and got it working, thanks! - UUID=affd0ac6-f3da-4f88-ac22-65d94dc5da8c       media/data      ext4    auto,users,exec                 0       0